# ColorBox, close on redirect

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I'm using ColorBox for some forms, but what I'd like to do is for one particular case if the form submits successful, instead of redirecting within the colorbox, I want it to redirect the parent window (outside the colorbox).

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location = '...';
```

try that out on return